# Different pages > terms & conditions > different pages

Tags: php, redirect

This is going to be tricky to explain, but i'm having trouble with a 'terms & conditions' page.

I need to make ONE terms & conditions, but different pages get the user to this terms, and depending the page he came from, after agreeing, he gets redirected to the correspondent page.

kind of

A1.php > terms & conditions.php > A2.php

B1.php > terms & conditions.php > B2.php

This terms & conditions page is the same for everyone, but how can i make her redirect depending on where the user came from? Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Lucas, how are you getting the link for the next page? I mean, the page that must open after Terms and Conditions are accepted, the link to that page, how do you get it or where do you get it from?

Answer (score 2):

What most people to, and what works the most reliable, is to add some kind of url variable. Instead of redirecting to `terms_and_conditions.php`, you instead redirect like this:

```
B1.php > terms_and_conditions.php?redirect=A2.php > A2.php
B1.php > terms_and_conditions.php?redirect=B2.php > B2.php
```

Comment: This way, some people who knows this may see the url, and just type "A2.php" on the browser and skip the Terms and conditions, right ?

Comment: Yes. But if you rely on the URL being 'secret' for security, you don't have much security at all. If you want to track if a person really saw (and accepted) the terms and conditions, you need to store that information somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Next is a real example of how to do it. Lucas, you will have to create 5 text files, name them with the next given names, copy-paste the codes to the corresponding files, and, finally, open your browser and type : "localhost/a1.php" and "localhost/b1.php".

**a1.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is A1. To enter A2 you have to accept Terms and Conditions.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="terms_and_conditions.php">
      <input type="text" value="a2.php" name="next_page" style="display:none"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Go to Terms and Conditions"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**b1.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is B1. To enter B2 you have to accept Terms and Conditions.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="terms_and_conditions.php">
      <input type="text" value="b2.php" name="next_page" style="display:none"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Go to Terms and Conditions"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**terms_and_conditions.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    Terms and Conditions
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Bla bla bla bla bla ...
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_POST['next_page']; ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Accept Terms and Conditions"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**a2.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is A2. Thanks for accepting Terms and Conditions.
  </body>
</html>
```

**b2.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is B2. Thanks for accepting Terms and Conditions.
  </body>
</html>
```

The tricky part is in **terms_and_conditions.php**. Pay attention to the **action**, which value comes from PHP. This is how only one Terms and Conditions can be used by many pages.

The page to open next is in **a1.php** and **b1.php**. Take a look at the input text named "next_page" (display:none). The "value" will have to change for every page.

Comment: Hello Jose, thank you for your reply. I get it! It's kind of sending a hidden input with a setted value. The problem goes deeper when i tell you that I can't change the pages A1/B1 source code. The only thing that i can do is tell what link goes to the Terms and Conditions. Is there a way out?

Comment: If many pages must jump to other pages through Terms and Conditions, the first pages MUST KNOW what are their corresponding next pages, so Terms and Conditions will be able to get this data and use it to open the next pages. Lucas said The only thing that i can do is tell what link goes to the Terms and Conditions, well, that link is what Terms and Conditions requires, the problem is, HOW TO PASS THE LINK to Terms and Conditions. In my answer we are using a HTML form, but there is another way : to store the link in PHP session. All depends on how Lucas is getting the link (by form or session).